# How do I put single quotes inside of other single quotes?

Tags: php, html

I have this code inside of a php echo, which is inside of an if statement. I need to do this line of code, but the quotes are giving me a problem. 
echo "

```
<a href="#' onclick='popup('popUpDiv')"><img src='$pic'></a>";
```

Then I tried to do this, where image.php was the code above, and I don't think the variable carries over.

```
<?php include 'image.php'; ?>
```

How would I go about fixing this?

And do you need the full page code?

Answer (score 0):

You can surround them with different quotes in HTML (some of your HTML quotes were unbalanced). In PHP you'll have to escape the inner quotes:

```
echo "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"popup('popUpDiv')\"><img src='$pic'></a>";
```

Comment: but why? you could just do `'<a href="#" onclick="popup(popUpDiv)"<img src="', $pic ,'"/></a>';`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy the default for `popup(popUpDiv)` would mean that you're (somewhere) declaring `popUpDiv` as a predefined variable if I'm not mistaken. When you surround it with quotes you're passing the string `"popUpDiv"` to the function. Since I'm not sure what they're doing based on the incomplete code I wouldn't assume anything.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$pic='image.jpg';
echo '<a href="#" onclick="popup(\'popUpDiv\')"><img src="'.$pic.'"></a>';
```

will produce this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
```

But you should be acccesing the `onclick` event through the DOM (inside `<script>` or better yet an external `js` file) and not using an href with an `#`.